# Изменение внешнего вида окна, созданного вызовом confirm в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер! В одном своем проекте я использую JavaScript функцию `confirm`, код выглядит вот так:

```
// Событие click, которое реагирует на нажатие кнопки "Очистить всё"
$('#reload').click(function () {
    function refresh() {
        if (confirm('Вы уверенны, что хотите перезагрузить страницу? На странице может использоваться введенная Вами информация, при перезагрузке она будет потерянна! Продолжить?')) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    refresh();
});
```

Все работает, вопросов никаких нет. Но есть такой вопрос - можно, используя какой-либо плагин jQuery, например, [Noty v2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149665/), заменить внешний вид окна, которое создается при помощи функции `confirm`? Так сказать на более респектабельное...

Comment: окна alert,confirm не поддаются стилизации.НУжно использовать либо готовые плагины либо создавать подобие через CSS(например создать блок полупрозрачный на всю страницу и показывать или показывать его по событию)

Comment: Ну так вы сами и ответили на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Noty — это такой jQuery плагин, который без особых проблем и манипуляций позволяет легко создавать сообщения вида alert — success — error — warning — information, или просто заменять скучные стандартные alert и promt диалоги....

Но про confirm ничего не сказано, к сожалению...

Comment: `confirm` всего лиш модальное окно с двумя кнопками `Ok` и `Cancel` никто не мешает использовать в этих целях любое другое модальное окно с таким же функционалом, но более солидным внешним видом, следовательно *можно, используя какой-либо плагин jQuery, например, Noty v2, заменить внешний вид окна, которое создается при помощи функции `confirm`*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если `confirm` полноценный, он должен останавливать выполнение кода, как и алерт, как и промпт. Все плагниы, что приведены - лишь обычные окна с колбеками. Реализацию, которая б повторяла встроенные методы НЕТ.

Comment: Никогда не делайте категоричных заявлений, рискуете показаться не очень умным человеком.
Имея немного желания почитать маны, можно выяснить что у JQuery есть метод event.preventDefault(); http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ Дальше продолжать или догадаетесь? )))

Comment: @Павел Вершинин с удовольствием бы понаблюдал как Вы реализуете блокировку переключения по вкладкам браузера с помощью плагинов "всемогущего" `Jquery`, что и является побочным эффектом при использовании `confirm`. опять таки в ответе указана остановка кода и продолжение его исполнения, после закрытия окна `confirm`, preventDefault же лишь отменяет текущее событие установленное по умолчанию и то не всегда.

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли, нет в этом посте. А то что я искал с остановкой кода то такого не нашел. И превент дефаулт и близко не повторяет того функционала что нам нужно. Это отмена действия по умолчанию, но никак не остановка кода, как правильно заметил FLK.Если критикуете @Павел Вершинин пожалуйста приводите доводы кодом, а не просто пустые слова. И не говорил категорично что этого НИЗЯ СДЕЛАТЬ, можно все нужно лишь иметь светлую голову на плечах.

Comment: @FLK 

1) Полная блокировка браузера, как вы правильно заметили, является ПОБОЧНЫМ эффектом и этого надо избегать для удобства пользователя.

2) Специально для вас, накатал простейший пример который демонстрирует, полноценный confirm на Noty http://p-wershinin.narod.ru/confirm.html

Comment: @markuper

Прошу прощения, что был излишне резок. Просто бесит когда кто-то заявляет что что-то сделать невозможно.)))

Мой пример по ссылке выше и для вас тоже. Понятно, что он НЕ универсален, но для примера я думаю вполне достаточно)

Comment: На всякий случай напомню, что в Firefox и Opera модальные окошки не такие уж и модальные — они не дают взаимодействовать лишь со страницей, весь остальной браузер остаётся доступным.

Comment: @Павел Вершинин, Сделать копию (без popup) - невозможно!
Confirm - синхронная функция, но реагирует на действия пользователя... Добейтесь такого))

Единственный способ: открываем popup, а текущий поток/окно в бесконечный цикл, ожидая изменения некой переменной, которую установит popup

Comment: @timka_s В 99.9% случаев, полностью останавливать работу на время пока пользователь нажмет кнопку в confirm нет никакой необходимости. Достаточно прервать активное действие и снова инициировать его после реакции пользователя, ну и конечно заблокировать страничку от "лишних" действий пользователя сплешскрином. Все как в моем примере который я привел выше. 

PS К сожалению дальнейшая дискуссия невозможна, через четыре часа самолет, пора собираться. Но через недельку можем продолжить :)

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос можно закрывать!

**UPD** Noty v2 может создавать альтернативные сообщения аналогичные стандартным окна, в том числе созданные функцией confirm, более подробная информация и демо - [тут](http://needim.github.com/noty/).

[Noty v2 на GitHub](https://github.com/needim/noty).

Comment: 2 плюса за незнание английского языка и не владение основами js. noty v2 не заменяет, а создает альтернативные сообщения, которые не имеют ничего общего с системными.